# Issue in QTCreator

Tags: ubuntu, qt-creator

I'm getting this error while opening the `.user` file of my project despite both `.user` file and the `QTcreator` installed in my system are of same version.

I even checked if my files are proper and they are proper and not corrupted.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAJWW.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text of the error message and the code that is causing it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you are stuck, you could try renaming the .user file to something else (close Qt Creator first) then re-running Qt Creator and re-opening the project. It will create a new .user file that is hopefully valid.